# How to respond to potential conflicts of interest in answers

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I mention my own products in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers)
>   [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)
>   [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

I've come across several answers within a particular tag in which an answerer will recommend a specific product that is made by the company for whom the user works. The answerer does not mention their association with the company. The product addresses a rather niche segment of the developer community. The asker is not asking about the product in particular; the exchange is more of the form:

Q: I want to do *Foo*. 
A: *Bar* can do *Foo* for you.

To be fair, the answerer often provides a reasonably detailed explanation of how the product can address the problem.

How does this community feel about these kind of answers?  Are they acceptable, or should they be flagged?

Comment: Some reading on the subject - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: It's in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: Need to find 2 more different dupes.

Comment: I looks bad... I know :P But this topic has been covered...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145583/when-should-we-be-enforcing-the-affiliation-requirement

Comment: Yowza.  I tried to find previous answers but my search-fu was not strong.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

I usually check the answerer's other answers.

If there's only one such answer, I usually assume that they were genuinely trying to be helpful and were unaware of the site's [policy about disclosing affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion). In such circumstances, I'll leave a friendly comment indicating that disclosure of affiliation is required.

If the answerer has multiple answers, all suggesting their product and none (or few) with disclosure of affiliation, I'll usually flag each with an "other" flag*, with the note suggesting that the answer is probably spam. I'm especially likely to flag if I see many such posts in short duration, or the posts are of the form "Bar can do Foo for you" without much explanation.

---

<sub>* I usually (not always) reserve the "spam" flag for outright "click here for cheap watches" type spam.</sub>