# Is it ok to Mention company name in answer or question?

Tags: discussion

I come across a question where a person mention his company name in answer.

Name of company has nothing to do with answer.

But a question come in my mind is : Should any one do this?

Is it consider as wrong? (Because I am thinking so.)

What community think about this?

One Example : [IPhone app and Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029815/iphone-app-and-web-services)

I have comment on that answer. So it may happen that when you visit link he has remove company name.

I am not sure for which tag to use. So if you find it wrong please make edit.

Comment: It's very likely to be spam in the example case you cited.  Flag it as such.

Comment: The spammer probably found the word "outsourcing" in the question. The company seems to sell iOS programming services.

Comment: Usually a mention of company employment is only done as disclosure of bias or as a source for reference. That being said, as long as it is relevant, it doesn't seem to be damaging so long as there isn't a whole shpeal which amounts to an advertisement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the affiliation is relevant to the post, then not only *should* the poster disclose it but he *[must](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145583/162102)*.  Going beyond disclosure to an actual link to the company home page is a little tacky but probably not actionable.

If the affiliation has nothing to do with the post, however, then it's a tagline or signature, not content relevant to the question, and [should be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/162102).  The proper venue for advertising your company, projects, web site, or anything else is the user profile.